# Permission Denied error trying to access MacOS shared folder on my raspberrypi

Tags: samba, macos

I have an HD plugged on my mac mini shared over my local network through SMB.
I want to mount this folder on my raspberrypi using:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER_IP/FOLDER ~/macshare/ -o user=USER
```

but after i type the password i get:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

At first i thought it was a problem with my credentials by i'm very sure i'm typing them correctly.
I think the problem migth be in some configuration on my mac, however if i try to access that folder from another mac it works fine.
Did anyone try to do something like this? Any help?

Comment: This Question is unclear - What **EXACTLY** did you type? "~" is meaningless with sudo. `sudo mount.cifs //Milliways.local/Images /mnt/Image -o user=…` works for me.

Comment: @Milliways `sudo mount -t cifs //SERVER_IP/FOLDER /home/pi/macshare/ -o user=USER`
I also tried to mount on `/mnt/macshare` but nothing. Is your folder shared by a mac?

Comment: What are the two Mac versions? - the one you can connect with, and the one you can't?

Comment: both Catalina, and i'm trying to connect in both cases to my mac mini.
case 1: raspberry to mac mini = doesen't work
case2: macbook to mac mini = work